# How to create an arbitrary HashMap to use in rust rocket for a web API

Tags: rust, serialization, serde, rust-rocket

I try to make a web API with rocket to try out the framework. I managed to return paginated results with a special struct that implements serializable.

However, the API I try to build depends on arbitrary values in a special dictionary. The received values may be strings, integers, bools, or other complex objects. The problem now is, that I'm not able to create a struct that contains "any" since `Any` is not serializable.

The basic idea would be something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Foobar<'a> {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub data: HashMap<&'a str, ??????>,
}
```

Even with enums, the problem remains since there is an infinite count of variations. Let's say, I use an enum to determine strings, bools, integers. When the containing type is another type, I need the json representation of that specific type. Basically another map with string -> any.

The current idea would be to use:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Foobar {
    pub id: Uuid,
    pub data: HashMap<String, rocket::serde::json::Value>,
}
```

But I don't know how the API will fare when there are non json values (e.g. msgpack).

Has somebody accomplished such a feat with rust/rocket?

Comment: To clarify, you are getting data from this "special dictionary" and returning it from a Rocket route, right? That's why its both `Serialize` and `Deserialize`? Is the data not specific to each operation so you can have specific types and make `Foobar<'a, T>` itself generic? Will the data format you're returning from Rocket always JSON encoded? I may be wrong, but I think `Value` can express the entirety of the [serde data-model](https://serde.rs/data-model.html) (though just might not look good for binary data and the like) so using it is probably fine.

Comment: Exactly. I tried several options and now ended up with using my own variant of `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

After several tries with traits and `std::any::Any`, I ended up with:

```rust
pub type DataObject = HashMap<String, DataValue>;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, ToSchema)]
pub enum DataValue {
    String(String),
    Integer(i64),
    Float(f64),
    Boolean(bool),
    Date(String),
    Time(String),
    DateTime(String),
    Reference(DataObject),
    ArrayReference(Vec<DataObject>),
}
```

This is - more or less - the same as `serde_json::Value`. It helps to further check the values and validate them against a possible type description of the objects.